# Show that $G^n$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $G$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

Let $G$ be a group. For $n\in\Bbb N$, let $G^n=\{x^n : x\in G\}$

**Show that $G^n$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $G$ is abelian**

I know that $x\in G^n$ therefore $G^n$ is a non empty subset of G. If we let $x^n, y^n\in G^n$, then as G is abelian, we know $x^n.y^n$ = $(xy)^n$ by commuting the $x$'s and $y$'s; therefore, $G^n$ is closed under multiplication

I'm trying to show that if $x^n\in G^n$ then $(x^n)^{-1}\in G^n$ but $(x^n)^{-1}=x^{-n}$ and the original condition was that $n\in\Bbb N$ so $-n$ would not be a natural number and therefore the inverse is not an element of $G^n$, which is obviously contradicting what I'm trying to show.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: What $x^{-n}$ means? For sure you know that $(x^n)^{-1}=(x^{-1})^n$ (Why?).

Comment: Is this just because of the index laws? So $(x^{-1})^n\in G^n$ because $x^{-1}\in G$?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure of knowing what do you mean by index laws, but it is easy to check anyway. About your other question: yes. Also take a little bit of care about non-emptiness of $G^n$. Who is $x$?

Comment: Can we not assume that $x^1$ is an element of $G^n$?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is abelian, then $xy = yx$ for all $x,y\in G$. Then, note that, if $$x,y \in G \Rightarrow x,y,y^{-1}\in G \Rightarrow x^n, y^n, y^{-n} \in G^n \Rightarrow x^ny^{-n} = (xy^{-1})^n \in G^n$$

The last step can be expanded as follows:
$$
 (xy^{-1})^n = (xy^{-1})(xy^{-1})\dots(xy^{-1}) = (xy^{-1}y^{-1}x)\dots(xy^{-1}) = (x^2y^{-2})\dots(xy^{-1}) = \cdots
$$

Then you are done because the condition you need to check for a subgroup is $s, t \in S \Rightarrow st^{-1} \in S$, and this has been verified above for $s = x^n, t = y^n$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a mistake in the beginning of your proof. The statement that $x\in G^n$ does not make sense since $x$ is not defined. Every element in $G^n$ must be able to be written in the form of $x^n$ for some $x\in G$. In fact, you can prove that $G^n$ is nonempty by saying that $e=e^n\in G^n$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

To prove that $G^n$ is a subgroup of $G$, let $a,b\in G^n$, you need to show that $ab,a^{-1}\in G^n$. Since $a,b\in G^n$, by definition, $a=x^n,b=y^n$ where $x,y\in G$. You did the part that $ab\in G^n$ correctly. So now we want to show that $a^{-1}\in G^n$. Notice $a^{-1}=(x^n)^{-1}=(x^{-1})^n=z^n$ where $z=x^{-1}\in G$. This means that $a^{-1}\in G^n$ and you can conclude that $G^n$ is a subgroup of $G$.

The property that you missed is that for any group $G$(not necessarily abelian) and $x\in G$, $n\in \Bbb{Z}$, $$(x^{n})^{-1}=(x^{-1})^n$$
It is a good exercise for you to verify this by induction.

Answer (score -1):

i) Let a€G,b€G => a^n€G^n ,b^n€G^n

To show (ab)^n€G^n

a€G,b€G => ab€G  (since G is group)

Then (ab)^n€G^n.

ii) Let a€G => a^n€G^n

To show (a^n)-¹€G^n

a€G => a-¹€G  (since G is group)

Therefore if a-¹€G => (a-¹)^n€G^n

We know (a-¹)^n = (a^n)-¹

So, (a-¹)^n€G^n => (a^n)-¹€G^n.

Therefore G^n is a subgroup of G.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If a€G is supposed to mean "a is in G", then I recommend using $\in$ instead; e.g. $a \in G$. Also, format the equations with LaTeX. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is not readable.